# Program is not responding, debugging says 'Value cannot be null'

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

```
using System;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Shooter
{
  class Player
   {
    //Animation representing player
    public Texture2D PlayerTexture;
    //Position of player relative to left side of screen
    public Vector2 Position;
    public bool playerActive;
    public int playerHealth;
    public int Width
    {
        get { return PlayerTexture.Width; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return PlayerTexture.Height; }
    }



    public void Initialize(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
    {
        PlayerTexture = texture;

        //sets the position of player to middle of the screen

        Position = position;

        playerActive = true;

        playerHealth = 100;


    }



    public void Update()
    {

    }


    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerTexture, Position, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }

}
}
```

This is my code, for my player class, and the program has no compiling errors. However, when I run the game, it states that "Game1 has stopped responding" and when I debug, there is an error message that says "value cannot be null". I am following the tutorial for Windows game development with XNA here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tarawalker/2012/12/10/windows-8-game-development-using-c-xna-and-monogame-3-0-building-a-shooter-game-walkthrough-part-2-creating-the-shooterplayer-asset-of-the-game/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error and your code I suppose this is your only class? If so, the tutorial that you are using is a bit weird. Because it definitely covers beginners material, but it skips some crucial information.

In monogame your first class should always inherit from the Game class. For the basic structure of a game in monogame/ XNA I would advice you to read the following article: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/monogame-project-template